# Wiki special:export export 'Special pages' such as title=Special:DoubleRedirects

Tags: mediawiki

Is this possible or am I missing something? What I am attempting to do is quickly export list to xml or get into a csv. Attempted a myriad of strings and referred to the MediaWiki_Administrator's_Handbook to no avail. Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Please improve this question. It is unclear what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of these queries through the api: see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page